# How to put p tag and span tag in a single line

Tags: html, css

I have a `p` and `span` tag i want to put them in a single line, Can anyone help me how to do this?

this is how my tags look:

```css
#h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 268px;
  margin-left: 116px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#heart {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 210px;
}

.close {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="h3">
  thiss is me
</p>
<span><i class="fa fa-heart" id="heart"></i><span class="close">x</span></span>
<!--i have a heart icon -->
```

I want to set all of them in a single line, But in my code when i try to add more details in the p tag all these other `#heart` and `.close` goes down along the way.

Can anyone please help, so that no matter what the content is these `heart` and `close` remain on top corner, their position does not change.

Comment: Um... `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Why not put the `<span>` inside the `<p>`

Comment: I tried that too, but as i said i want heart and close on the corner-fixed. when i change the content of the p tag they all seem to go down.

Comment: positon absolute inside the p

Comment: display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem.Thank you.

```css
#h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 268px;
  margin-left: 116px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
 display: flex; 
flex-direction: row;

}

#heart {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
   
   
}

.close {
  font-size: 18px;
 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="h3">
  this is me .Check this out .What I have done.This answer solved my problem <span><i class="fa fa-heart" id="heart"></i><span class="close">x</span>
</p>
   
<!--i have a heart icon -->
```